# how to write c/c++ extension for adobe air(or flex)

Tags: c++, apache-flex, air, air-native-extension

is there a official sdk for c/cpp programmer to write extension for AIR or FLEX?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/flex/ I'm not sure if it's c/c++

Answer (score 3):

This will happen soon. Adobe posted this document today : http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/devices/pdfs/DevelopingActionScriptExtensionsForAdobeAIR.pdf

It's only for AIR for TV yet but they said it will be available for AIR for mobiles next

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PixelBender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html) to do certain image based calculations in C/C++.  There is also a little known project called [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) which was meant to use existing C/C++ libraries in Flash, however this project is fully supported yet and I don't recommend using it because results are varied.

Comment: PixelBender has nothing to do with C/C++. The syntax of the language is based on C, but it's not C/C++ at all. It gets executed in its own thread, that's the only thing special about it.